# Interrogative words with inversion and est-ce que

Tags: interrogative

Where do you put the interrogative words and est-ce que or inversion in a question?

For example, where would you put the interrogative word `combien`, inversion, and est-ce que in this question:

> How many dogs does Laetitia have?

Comment: I rolled back to the original version. The edits from version one to three were quite distasteful and looked weird for a experienced SX user like yourself. Was there some issue withe the edit or was it just some kind of homework panic? You do realize several people here are in the CET timezone and that you posted a around 1 AM in that zone, hence the few hours before an answer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Combien de chiens est-ce qu'elle a ? 
>   Combien de chiens est-ce que Lætitia a ?

Inversion:

> Combien de chiens a-t-elle ?
>   Combien de chiens a Lætitia ?

You just place them in the beginning, along with what you want to know the quantity of, in this case 'Dogs'.

Note: the euphonic 't' fixes the vowel hiatus.
Note: It's NOT *des chiens*, because many times 'de' is not followed by an article (The, a, etc) in *combien*, *beaucoup*, etc. (http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-combien-de-des-repas.460622/)